# How to include object in post method? HTTP

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I include an object in the body ? [Here](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#create-a-checkout) in the documentation it says Money object.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bhpm.png

Here's my code so far.

```
  var _url = "https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges";
  final String _key = 'APIKEY';
  final String _description = 'DESCRIPTION';
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {'name' : 'name' , 'description' : _description , 'pricing_type' : 'fixed_price' , 'localprice' : {'amount' : '1' , 'currency' : 'USD' }};
  Map<String, String> headers = {"X-CC-Api-Key": _key , "X-CC-Version": "2018-03-22"};

  http.Response res = await http.post(_url , body: body, headers: headers);
  var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an object and add a Money-Object by "setMoney" to the main object, the main object then will be send as payload in the body, that the way i do it. So creating objects and serialize it into json should do the trick. Do you already use serializing/marschalling with Gson or any other libary? Maybe this can help you : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "Content-Type":"application/json" in headers map:

```
Map headers = {
"Content-Type":"application/json", 
"X-CC-Api-Key": _key , 
"X-CC-Version": "2018-03-22"};
```